# How to call same method multiple times to add something

Tags: java

So im creating a gpa calculator, it takes the 4 classes (or more if i want) and calculates the letter grade and gpa weight.
How would i use the same method 4 times and each time have it add the different inputted variables.
For example, the first input of the first calling (for the grade) is an 80.
if i call it again and input a 90, I want it to store the inital 80 and add the 90 and so on so i can calculate the gpa.

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;

public class GpaCalculator{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    {
    System.out.println("Please enter your name>>>");
    Scanner stringinputs = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = stringinputs.nextLine();
    GreatGrader();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(name);
    }

}

public static void GreatGrader(){

Scanner stringinput = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter your course>>>");
String Course1 = stringinput.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is the weight of this class? Normal, Honors, or AP?>>>");
String weight = stringinput.nextLine();
System.out.println("What is your grade in the class?>>>");
String grade = stringinput.nextLine();

    double gpa = 0;
    if (weight.equalsIgnoreCase("honors"))
        gpa = gpa + 1;
    else if (weight.equalsIgnoreCase("Ap"))
        gpa = gpa + 1.5;
    else if (weight.equalsIgnoreCase("normal"));

        String letter;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int grades = in.nextInt();

        if (grades >= 96)
        {   gpa = 4.5; 
            letter = "A";}
        else if (grades >= 92)
        {   gpa = 4.0;
            letter = "A";}
        else if (grades >=88 )
        {   gpa = 3.5;
        letter = "B"; }
        else if (grades >= 84 )
        {   gpa = 3.0;
            letter = "B";}
        else if (grades >=76 )
        {   gpa = 2.5;
            letter = "C";}
        else if (grades >= 72)
            {gpa = 1.5;
            letter = "C";}
        else if (grades>=68)
        {       gpa = 1.0;
            letter = "D";}
        else if (grades <=67)
        {   gpa = 0;
            letter = "F";
        }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not store the values into a data structure like an array and pass it as a param into the method, such that you only call the method once?

Comment: how would i do that?

Comment: If i didn't misread, you want to sum up the score in order to calculate the GPA? Edit: ignore my previous comment.

Comment: Yeah, how would i store the inputted grade each time so i could calculate the gpa after 4 or so runs

Comment: You could try wrapping it in a `do while` loop, and the condition is such that it will always repeat the process of `GreatGrader` until a certain key such as `esc` or `enter` is pressed to break out of the loop. To store values, you can store it in an array of primitive type `double`.

Comment: You would use a loop - for example you could ask the user "Do you want to enter another class?" and as long as they answer with something like "yes" you continue to prompt for the data and store it in the next element of a List (or array if you prefer, but then you have to worry about resizing)

Comment: Okay i think i got it, thanks guys